# I got No container found for web_1 when entering docker-compose web bash with strange logs output

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

I try to run existing laravel project under docker with Dockerfile in file :
I got No container found for web_1 when entering docker-compose web bash with strange logs output...

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:   // I USE THIS NAME IN docker-compose command
    container_name: banners_web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - AdminRMQBannersDb

  admin_queue:
    container_name: banners_admin_queue
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - AdminRMQBannersDb

  AdminRMQBannersDb:
    container_name: banners_db
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: AdminRMQBannersDb
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - ./storage/dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 33063:3306
```

I run with success command :

```
docker-compose up -d --build

...
Step 1/5 : FROM php:8.0
---> 003ed854bebf
Step 2/5 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y         libfreetype6-dev         libjpeg62-turbo-dev         libmcrypt-dev         libpng-dev         zlib1g-dev         libxml2-dev         libzip-dev         libonig-dev         graphviz     && docker-php-ext-configure gd     && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd     && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql     && docker-php-ext-install mysqli     && docker-php-ext-install zip     && docker-php-ext-install sockets     && docker-php-ext-install exif     && docker-php-source delete     && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php --      --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
---> Using cache
---> 0d056eb8bbc1
Step 3/5 : WORKDIR /app
---> Using cache
---> cd6e19492328
Step 4/5 : COPY . .
---> Using cache
---> 3ddf261cce6f
Step 5/5 : RUN composer install
---> Using cache
---> 39753903d52d

Successfully built 39753903d52d
Successfully tagged adminbanners_web:latest
adminbanners_AdminRMQBannersDb_1 is up-to-date
Recreating adminbanners_web_1         ... done
Recreating adminbanners_admin_queue_1 ... done
```

I got strange output with "Interactive shell" message when check logs :

```
master@master-at-home:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/MS/AdminBanners$ docker logs --tail=50  -t    adminbanners_AdminRMQBannersDb_1
2023-03-01T07:02:34.995041539Z 2023-03-01T07:02:34.982625Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2023-03-01T07:02:34.995091472Z 2023-03-01T07:02:34.990096Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.22) starting as process 1 ...
2023-03-01T07:02:34.995098084Z 2023-03-01T07:02:34.994626Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2023-03-01T07:02:34.995102363Z 2023-03-01T07:02:34.994650Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2023-03-01T07:02:34.995106305Z 2023-03-01T07:02:34.994654Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2023-03-01T07:02:34.995110180Z 2023-03-01T07:02:34.994657Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2023-03-01T07:02:34.995114100Z 2023-03-01T07:02:34.994661Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2023-03-01T07:02:34.995118099Z 2023-03-01T07:02:34.994664Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2023-03-01T07:02:34.995121647Z 2023-03-01T07:02:34.994919Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-03-01T07:02:34.995168708Z 2023-03-01T07:02:34.995027Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2023-03-01T07:02:34.998104820Z 2023-03-01T07:02:34.996703Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2023-03-01T07:02:35.005609186Z 2023-03-01T07:02:35.005466Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-03-01T07:02:35.007700493Z 2023-03-01T07:02:35.007528Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2023-03-01T07:02:35.021099501Z 2023-03-01T07:02:35.020952Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2023-03-01T07:02:35.060178215Z 2023-03-01T07:02:35.059892Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2023-03-01T07:02:35.068285223Z 2023-03-01T07:02:35.060321Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-03-01T07:02:35.269012919Z 2023-03-01T07:02:35.268795Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2023-03-01T07:02:35.270310685Z 2023-03-01T07:02:35.269876Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2023-03-01T07:02:35.270339504Z 2023-03-01T07:02:35.269899Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2023-03-01T07:02:35.270346787Z 2023-03-01T07:02:35.270212Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2023-03-01T07:02:35.321410676Z 2023-03-01T07:02:35.320470Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.22 started; log sequence number 12359923
2023-03-01T07:02:35.321473712Z 2023-03-01T07:02:35.321003Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2023-03-01T07:02:35.321486756Z 2023-03-01T07:02:35.321003Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2023-03-01T07:02:35.340569771Z 2023-03-01T07:02:35.340393Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 230301  7:02:35
2023-03-01T07:02:35.348044376Z 2023-03-01T07:02:35.346537Z 0 [Warning] World-writable config file './auto.cnf' is ignored.
2023-03-01T07:02:35.348157373Z 2023-03-01T07:02:35.346654Z 0 [Warning] World-writable config file './auto.cnf' has been removed.
2023-03-01T07:02:35.348189944Z
2023-03-01T07:02:35.348195395Z 2023-03-01T07:02:35.347816Z 0 [Note] Salting uuid generator variables, current_pid: 1, server_start_time: 1677654154, bytes_sent: 0,
2023-03-01T07:02:35.348199314Z 2023-03-01T07:02:35.347912Z 0 [Note] Generated uuid: '0b5c0dae-b7ff-11ed-95ed-0242ac140002', server_start_time: 281476654364811, bytes_sent: 94370025228672
2023-03-01T07:02:35.348202868Z 2023-03-01T07:02:35.347948Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 0b5c0dae-b7ff-11ed-95ed-0242ac140002.
2023-03-01T07:02:35.367028703Z 2023-03-01T07:02:35.365407Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2023-03-01T07:02:35.367062076Z 2023-03-01T07:02:35.365984Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2023-03-01T07:02:35.369682151Z 2023-03-01T07:02:35.368452Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2023-03-01T07:02:35.369808838Z 2023-03-01T07:02:35.368496Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2023-03-01T07:02:35.369817753Z 2023-03-01T07:02:35.368723Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2023-03-01T07:02:35.369821761Z 2023-03-01T07:02:35.368778Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2023-03-01T07:02:35.404992904Z 2023-03-01T07:02:35.383361Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2023-03-01T07:02:35.405021655Z 2023-03-01T07:02:35.387486Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2023-03-01T07:02:35.405027782Z 2023-03-01T07:02:35.387526Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2023-03-01T07:02:35.405032422Z 2023-03-01T07:02:35.387532Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2023-03-01T07:02:35.405036827Z 2023-03-01T07:02:35.387557Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2023-03-01T07:02:35.405041338Z 2023-03-01T07:02:35.387561Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2023-03-01T07:02:35.405045491Z 2023-03-01T07:02:35.387574Z 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2023-03-01T07:02:35.405049591Z 2023-03-01T07:02:35.392367Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'user mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2023-03-01T07:02:35.405054368Z 2023-03-01T07:02:35.392403Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2023-03-01T07:02:35.424983248Z 2023-03-01T07:02:35.422276Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2023-03-01T07:02:35.425026866Z 2023-03-01T07:02:35.422678Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
2023-03-01T07:02:35.425033792Z Version: '5.7.22'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
master@master-at-home:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/MS/AdminBanners$ docker logs --tail=50  -t    adminbanners_admin_queue_1
2023-03-01T07:11:54.756491338Z Interactive shell
2023-03-01T07:11:54.756544962Z
2023-03-01T07:11:54.827446121Z php > master@master-at-home:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/MS/AdminBanners$ docker logs --tail=50  -t    adminbanners_web_1
2023-03-01T07:11:54.764404772Z Interactive shell
```

Why output of 2 last commands so strange? Seems I use valid format for logging checking...

and I failed to enter into bash :

```
master@master-at-home:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/MS/AdminBanners$ docker-compose exec web bash
ERROR: No container found for web_1
```

I tried to restart with command :

```
docker-compose restart
```

But got the same error entering the bash...

in my Dockerfile :

```
FROM php:8.0

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
libfreetype6-dev \
libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
libmcrypt-dev \
libpng-dev \
zlib1g-dev \
libxml2-dev \
libzip-dev \
libonig-dev \
graphviz \

&& docker-php-ext-configure gd \
&& docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
&& docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
&& docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
&& docker-php-ext-install zip \
&& docker-php-ext-install sockets \
&& docker-php-ext-install exif \
&& docker-php-source delete \
&& curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- \
--install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN composer install
```

How that can be fixed?

Comment: Should your Dockerfile specify a `CMD` to run to start the application?

Comment: Not sure, which CMD?

Comment: What should the container do when you run it?  Not an interactive shell, but some sort of `php` invocation?

Comment: I have RUN composer install - as I need to to run my laravel app...

Comment: Right, the `CMD` should run the actual Laravel application as a foreground process.

Comment: and usually that is what I really have in my docker installations. But not in this, which I got from some step by step manual. Really frasytarted why so strange output  with "Interactive shell" message and I can not enter into docker shell